# Primefaces 3.0.1 TabView p:ajax tabChange Event Not firing when Validation Fails

Tags: primefaces

I'm unable to get the tabChange event to fire when the first form (id="form1") inputText doesn't have a value.  When I supply a value in the inputText the tabChange event will fire.  With that said the real question would be how to restructure the below so that the onChange will fire when the first tab's inputText if empty.  Each of my tab's have different forms since they each have data entry and processing that is specific to each tab.

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
   <h:head>
   </h:head>
   <h:body>
        <p:tabView>
            <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{tabBean.onTabChange}"/>
            <p:tab title="Tab I">
                <h:form id="form1">
                    <p:inputText value="#{tabBean.inText}" required="true" requiredMessage="Required Field"/>
                    <p:commandButton value="test" actionListener="#{tabBean.submit}"/>
                </h:form>
            </p:tab>
            <p:tab title="Tab II">
                <h:form id="form2">
                    tab 2 content
                </h:form>
            </p:tab>
        </p:tabView>
    </h:body>
</html>

//Bean
public class TabBean extends BaseSessionBean{
    private String inText;

    public void onTabChange(TabChangeEvent event) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Tab Changed", "Active Tab: " + event.getTab().getTitle());

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }

    public void submit(ActionEvent actionEvent){
        System.out.println("form submitted");
    }

    public String getInText() {
        return inText;
    }

    public void setInText(String inText) {
        this.inText = inText;
    }
}
```

**one workaround: (remove required validation)**

```
<p:inputText value="#{adminBean.registerationLocation}">
                        <p:ajax event="blur"/>
                    </p:inputText>
```

Comment: The only workaround I've found is to remove the required="true" and validate when the blur event fires for the inputText so that the inputText wont be validated when the tabView's onChange fires as in my case the form being empty and the user going to another tab is desire. Updated code above.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `TabChangeEvent` with `AjaxBehaviorEvent`

> javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent